# How do I get tutorial for ubuntu application development

Tags: application-development

I would like to participate ubuntu appshowdown contest If I got time in this exam season . Before that I wanna learn python &pygtk  to create native ubuntu apps .

How do I get tutorial for it ? Is there any resources available from ubuntu ?

PS : I am already familiar with c/c++ and java . But I prefer python because ubuntu recommends it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are resources available on the Ubuntu App Developer site. Check out the [Ubuntu App Developer Cookbook](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/).

Answer (score 7):

There is an awesome tutorial that comes with the `quickly` package for developing Ubuntu applications.

Try `quickly tutorial ubuntu-application` for the tutorial.

There is also a video tutorial on how to use Quickly that promises to get you prepared in less than 5 minutes.

- http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/

Comment: @espectalll123 : ubuntu and its developer site both are open - sourced

Comment: please add tutorial links for  for pyGtk and Gtk.3.0 :-)

Comment: I acceptd your answer please improve this answer

Answer (score 1):

take a look at http://developer.ubuntu.com/
there are good resources and tutorials
also take a look at this [pygtk tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/index.html)

If you prefer pdf  use [this pdf](http://www.pygtk.org/dist/pygtk2-tut.pdf) or [this pdf](http://yeezi.googlecode.com/files/PyGTK%20tutorial.pdf)

also take a look at [www.gtk.org](http://www.gtk.org)

also you could use other libraries for other purposes